# How can i convert a yml,json or xml to csv

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I'm using the bundle "JMSSerializerBundle" for export retrieved entity data. I can export the results as json, xml or yml successfully.

But i need also a csv export for this results. This bundle can't handle csv export. But i'm also not sure how can i convert json,xml or yml to csv, because csv is a flat file.

Have anyone solve this issue before?

**Update**

Now i create an solution for my problem, i'm partially satisfied with my solution, because it is not recursive. I will show it.

```
 if ($format == 'csv') {
    $json = $serializer->serialize($query, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->enableMaxDepthChecks());
    return $this->toCsv(json_decode($json, true));
}


/**
 * @todo write an recursive function for deeper levels
 *
 * @param $data
 * @return array
 */
protected function toCsv($data)
{
    $headers = array();
    $outerCounter = 0;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $i => $j) {
            if (!is_array($j)) {
                $headers[] =  $i;
                $result[$outerCounter][$i] =  $j;
            } else {
                foreach ($j as $k => $m) {
                    if (!is_array($m)) {
                        $headers[] =  $i. '_'.$k;
                        $result[$outerCounter][$i. '_'.$k] = $m;
                    } else {
                        foreach ($m as $n => $l) {
                            if (!is_array($l)) {
                                $headers[] =  $i.'_'.$k.'_'.$n;
                                $result[$outerCounter][$i.'_'.$k.'_'.$n] =  $l;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $outerCounter++;
    }

    asort($headers);
    $headers = array_unique($headers);

    return array('headers' => $headers, 'data' => $result);
}
```

Comment: take a look at [this](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/291). Hope this help

Comment: I'm not sure if I have understood correctly. Should i define every property in this object "CsvLineObject"?